# How to fix this issue “Dummy Output” for Output device section and I can’t select any device in the “Input Device” section?

Tags: 20.04

Please note that the sound isn’t muted

I’m using Ubuntu 20.04 focal

[image]

Comment: Dummy output may appear when the sound driver didn't load. Please [edit] with `lshw -c sound` , `lspci` and `pactl list sinks`